# Prove that it's impossible to approximate $1/z$ with polynomials on an annulus

Tags: complex-analysis

I heard a nice problem, presumably from an old qual, that I thought I'd share.

**Problem:** Let A be the annulus (in the complex plane) $A=\{z: r_1 \leq |z|\leq r_2\}.$ Prove that $f(z) = 1/z$ cannot be approximated uniformly by polynomials on $A$.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If $f_n$ is a sequence of holomorphic functions converging uniformly to a holomorphic function $f$, then the contour integrals $\oint f_n$ of the $f_n$ around a circular contour converge to the contour integral $\oint f$. For $f = \frac{1}{z}$ the latter integral is nonzero, but it is zero for any sequence of polynomials $f_n$.

Comment: +1: is it possible to extend your argument such that it works also for $f(z) =z^{-2}$?

Comment: @Fabian: sure. Replace $f_n, f$ above with $zf_n, zf$.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Why is $\oint f_n =0$ for each $n$?

Comment: Also,,,1/f is analytic on and inside of the given annular region,,,,,so by Cauchy gaursat,,, contour integral of 1/f is also 0

Comment: @Qiaochu Yuan so how do you describe now!!!

Answer (score 7):

Here is another simple argument that only requires the maximum principle. Suppose that $1/z$ can be approximated uniformly on $A$ by polynomials. Let $m:=\operatorname{min} \{|1/z| : z \in A\}>0$. Then by assumption, there exists some polynomial $P$ such that
$$|1/z - P(z)|<m \qquad (z \in A).$$
Thus,
$$|1-zP(z)|<m|z|\leq1 \qquad (z \in A).$$

By the maximum principle, 
$$|1-zP(z)| < 1$$
for every $z$ in the disk whose boundary is the outer circle of $A$. But with $z=0$ we get a contradiction.

Essentially the same proof shows that for every compact set $K$ in the plane whose complement contains more than one component, there exists some function $f$ holomorphic on a neighborhood of $K$ that cannot be approximed uniformly on $K$ by polynomials.

Comment: It is legit to set $z=0$?

Comment: @WilsonofGordon Yes, why not? The obtained inequality $|1-zP(z)|<1$ holds for all $z$ in a disc containing zero.

Comment: But the set $A$ on which our discussion is based is an annulus!

Comment: the function $1-zP(z)$ is holomorphic everywhere in the plane. By the argument in the answer, it is less than $1$ in modulus on the exterior boundary of the annulus $A$. Hence, by the maximum modulus principle, it is less than one in the whole disk whose boundary is the outer circle of $A$.